# check log file if job status is not started

Tags: linux, scripting, read, logs

I would like to create Linux shell script which reads a log file.

for eg. I have log file with lines:

```
Job: One(106) started.
Job: Two(107) started.
Job: Name(111) started.
Job: EXE(112) started.
Job: SMTG(117) started.
...........
.....
...
```

I want to make script which checks all jobs and sends email if job status is not started. Job status could be error, locked, stopped and everything else. I don't know how to write script to check exactly if status is not started.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$0!~/started/{print}' logfile | mail -s "Jobs not started" abc@xyz.com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -v 'Job:.*started.' yourfile.log | while read line; do
    # your not started line is here
    echo $line
done
```

Little explanation:
`grep` will read your file and filter out lines matching a pattern, so we don't match started jobs. Then you are reading not started lines, you can replace `echo $line` and send an email there.

Comment: useless use of cat award.. http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: Oh, well. I think it's just clearer to read, but ok, I've changed it.